# NPM install node-sass@ cannot succeed

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

It failed to `npm intall` **angular-cli** and I traced it to node-sass. 
And it failed to install it alone.

Here is what happened. Anyone know what to do ?

```
$ sudo npm install -g node-sass@^4.0.0
/usr/local/bin/node-sass -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:887:18)
    at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.8.1 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.12\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.8.1
gyp verb command install [ '8.8.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.8.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.8.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.8.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/npuser/.npm/_logs/2017-10-28T05_28_22_601Z-debug.log
```

Comment: does `sudo chown -R yourusername /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue while installing node-sass and it seems it is not resolved yet. As a workaround you can use --unsafe-perm flag.

sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true -g node-sass

Here is the reference from node-sass "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md"

Answer (score 0):

When you install something and get error like

```
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
```

it's means installation need some permission to add folder or file to another folder.

So try to give permission on installation like

```
sudo npm install node-sass
```